# How to add a library to webpacker to use in Stimulus JS Controllers

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, stimulusjs

I want to to use the [dayjs](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs) library ([instead of moment)](https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs) within my [Stimulus](https://stimulusjs.org/) js Controller, but I keep getting an error that says:

> dayjs is not defined

```
setNextVisit(event) {
  console.log( dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD') );
}
```

[image]

I'm using Rails 5.2 with Webpacker and Stimulus.

I added *dayjs* via `yarn add dayjs --save` which add this to `/package.json`:

**/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "meh",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/webpacker": "3.5",
    "dayjs": "^1.8.2"
    "stimulus": "^1.1.1",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.2"
  }
}
```

To wire-up dayjs in webpack via the webpacker gem, I've added this to `/app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

**/app/javascript/packs/application.js**

```
/* eslint no-console:0 */

// @RAILS/UJS
// imported in config/webpack/environment.js
Rails.start();

// TURBOLINKS
import Turbolinks from 'turbolinks';
Turbolinks.start();

// DAYJS
import dayjs from 'dayjs'

// STIMULUS
import { Application } from 'stimulus'
import { definitionsFromContext } from "stimulus/webpack-helpers"


const application = Application.start()
const context = require.context("./controllers", true, /\.js$/)
application.load(definitionsFromContext(context))
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to import dayjs in your stimulus controller not in the main application.js

Your controller should look something like that:

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus";
import dayjs from 'dayjs'

export default class extends Controller {    

  SetNextVisit(event) {
    console.log( dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD') );
 }

}
```

This is not specific to Stimulus but how ES6 JS works